# Center Aligning an input

Tags: css, input, center

I would like to know how to center align my input on my page. Thanks

```
 <body>

 <input id="ask" type="text" placeholder = "Ex: how tall is the Gateway Arch" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Ex: how tall is the gateway arch'"/>

<style type="text/css">
    #ask {

        padding: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
        font-size:45px;
        background-color:#FAFAFA;
        min-width: 500px;
        padding: 0 auto;
        border: 0 none;
        </style>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to center align your input form, correct? That is easy. If you want to center anything in the `<body>` tag or a `<div>` tag, or you want to center the input form itself, you simply add the following css:

`margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`

Try some code like:

`input {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}`

Comment: That just caused the text to be center aligned:(

Comment: Wait wait, use `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto`